# php fputcsv use semicolon separator in CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

I wrote a code where I retrieve data from DB and populate them in CSV using the function 'fputcsv'

I put on top the following:

```
$file = fopen("internal/customer_info.csv","w");
```

Then I retrieve the data and put them in variables, run the function:

```
$customerInfo = $first_name.";".$last_name.";".$address1.";".$address2.";".$postcode.";".$city.";".$country.";".$email;
fputcsv($file,explode(';',$customerInfo));
```

And finally, I closed the file.

My question is:
How can I put a semicolon separator? As you can see I have semicolon there but the CSV output does not. It shows a comma instead.

Why's that? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You do something with `fputcsv()`, your don't get what you want. So please look at the documentation of that function, especially at the function signature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The delimiter can be set by using the third parameter of `fputcsv()`:

> int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, **string $delimiter = ","** [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\" ]]] )

Please change:

```
fputcsv($file,explode(';',$customerInfo));
```

to:

```
fputcsv($file,explode(';',$customerInfo), ";");
```

Please check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) before asking on Stack Overflow.